# How to concatenate json result elements with JsonPath (JayWay)

Tags: json, concatenation, jsonpath, jayway

I have this JSON response:

```
{
  "agreedToTermsOfUse": true,
  "firstName": "Admin",
  "lastName": "iConsulto",
  "middleName": "",
  "status": 0,
  "timeZoneId": "UTC",
}
```

and I am trying to concatenate the first name and the last name.

I have tried to do this:

```
$..concat($..firstName," ",$..lastName)
```

but it returns me an empty value.
I have also try this:

```
$..concat("+",$..lastName)
```

And it has returned me this:

```
+["lastNameUser"]
```

Any ideas about why the second one option returns me something (like a list) and the first one doesn't return anything??
I have tried also this:

```
$..concat("+",$..lastName[0])
```

but it doesn't return me just the last name with the plus symbol.

So... How I can concatenate both names?? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score -2):

The Solution is applicable only to [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) implementation.

Do not use the deep scan `..` operator while concatenating.

Try the below JSONPath-expression

```
$.concat($.firstName," ",$.lastName)
```

Online Tool: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

[image]

Comment: It doesn't show me anything. I think this is because firstName and lastName returns lists, but using $.lastName[0] doesn't work either :(

Comment: are you sure you have posted the exact json in the question and not a part of it? It works in https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ (online tool for jayway)

Comment: I am using this exact example and it doesn't work

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno This is specific for Jayway JSONPath and not other implementations of JSONPath. It's not in the proposed standard specification.

Comment: I didn't even realize there was a difference. I think I will pose my question on the JayWay GH page then